# Unable to get the results from python script when using shell_exec() in php

Tags: php, python, terminal

I need to get the result of python script run in terminal and it be used in php so i had tried with shell_exec, exec, passthru, system. Now the problem was the python script take more time to generate the result(upto 45 secs) so it would be returned empty result. if i am used sample python script(just print one array) it working fine with those php functions(shell_exec,exec,system,passthru). What i do for myself to resolve the problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show your code and describe exactly what's working and what isn't.

Comment: Are you wanting the standard output (stdout), the exit status, or both from the executed python script?  Show us the code you are attempting to execute to retrieve these results.  Include an example of the output from the python script when ran alone.

Comment: //my php code
$output = shell_exec('python3 ActorArrayMatcher_FS.py');
print_r($output);

Comment: when you run ActorArrayMatcher_FS.py this return some output?

Comment: @NanheKumar No it returns empty result(NULL)

Comment: simple if python3 ActorArrayMatcher_FS.py return nothing then how can php show any output simply write print("test"); in python file then run php script.

Comment: @NanheKumar   i had tried with sample python file just print one array. it's working fine

Comment: First run python3 ActorArrayMatcher_FS.py share your output.

Comment: @NanheKumar sorry you can't get me what i am say. ActorArrayMatcher_FS.py(the script contains 1600 lines and print at last) this file return empty result but working in terminal. instead of this file i am using sample.py it perfectly returns output. Problem was the script file loads more time even in terminal(take upto 45 secs)